# Routing messages for two parties received on the same endpoint in BizTalk

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-pipelines

I am receiving messages for two parties on the same endpoint. My receive port receives AS2 messages, not EDI, and I am trying to route this messages.

How can I route the messages I receive to a different locations for each party?

Answer (score 0):

The usual method is to have a field in either the payload or headers that you mark as a promoted property in the schema, and then have filters on your send port that subscribe to that.